# Why does't the export command work on PS1

Tags: bash

I'm trying to set PS1 as "KeepPrompt", and prevent it from being changed while entering into a subshell. To do that I entered the following:

```
user@host:~$ echo $SHLVL 
user@host:~$ 1 
user@host:~$ export PS1="KeepPrompt: "
KeepPrompt:  
KeepPrompt: echo $SHLVL
KeepPrompt: 1
KeepPrompt: bash 
user@host:~$ 
user@host:~$ echo $SHLVL 
user@host:~$ 2
```

As you see when I try to create a new subshell, the PS1 definition doesn't survive entering into the new shell. Why is it so?

Comment: Absolutely right. +1 for being so informative!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you initialize a (bash) (sub)shell [several files are sourced](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html).

For me (and I think that is default in Ubuntu) `PS1` will be overwritten by `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`.

Also, `/etc/profile` sets `$PS1`, but only when it is empty.

---

Best would be to add this at the end of your `.bashrc`:

```
PS1="KeepPrompt: "
```